# Dependency visualization of classes

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, external-dependencies

I experiment with javascript webgl library [awayjs](https://github.com/awayjs/awayjs-full/issues/1), and there is a DisplayObjectContainer, the basic class for all objects which can be added on scene. I want to see all classes  which extends this class definition, how I can do that? I use VSCode, but I also can open project in Webstorm or Atom. I want do generate something like dependency tree graph, or if it is imposible simple jump to classes extends DisplayObjectContainer one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `Typescript: Dependency View` command in atom-typescript is what you're looking for.

See the section on "Dependency View" [here](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript) and read more about that feature [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/dependency-view.md).

Comment: Thank you for recomendation. This morning I tried to use this feature of atom ide and found it extremelly not comfortable. The reason is that it build extremellimely big graph and through a lot of errors. I also tied to use some filters (like display, DisplayObjectContainer) to make this graph smaller and visualise only those nodes which I need but it was still not usefull continue a lot of other dependencies. So I desided to make my own parser on python, to generate all extensions in json format.

Comment: This feature appears to have been removed since you posted originally.